# DropBox does not auto rename file during upload

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I'm using Dropbox Java API to upload file.

Following code does not upload file with auto rename:

```
void uploadFile(@NonNull final String inPath, @NonNull final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, DbxException {
    client.files()
        .uploadBuilder(inPath)
        .withMode(WriteMode.ADD)
        .withAutorename(true)
        .uploadAndFinish(inputStream);
}
```

Can you please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your question? Does does code work or does it not work? If it doesn't work, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: Are you sending twice the same file? I have observed the same thing when doing so, using two different files solved that issue.

Comment: @Loïc Yes. Your observation is correct.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Cannot-auto-rename-file/m-p/234665#M12824 ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that:
Dropbox does not consider there to be a conflict if you upload content identical to what's already in that file, and the rename will only occur on conflict.